# E-mail confirmation working on registration but not logon in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a website which has a lot of users before implementing e-mail verification. I use ASP.NET Core 1.1
I want new users e-mails to be verified but not previously registered members....
So now if I add this line to Startup.cs:

```
options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
```

previously registered users will need to have their e-mails validated and this is not practical in my site... If I set it to false then new users will receive an error if they open ConfirmEmail method... so I need a solution to be able to have it set to true but previously registered users are able to login without confirmation.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could take that line out of Startup.cs and handle the logic in your controller...

For example, create a bit column in the AspNetUsers table 'previousUser', and default it to 0. Set all previous users to 1. Then in your Login action of your controller have a check like something below:

```
if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user) && _context.Users.previousUser != true)
{
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You must have a confirmed email to log in.");
return View(await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model));
}
else
{
...sign in
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, isn't there a simple way just to disable the check on Login method?

Comment: Yeah, but then if new users don't confirm email they could still login...If that's the case kind of defeats the purpose...

Comment: I have some users who received verification e-mails so I don't want the site to crash... i hope you can find a solution as mentioned above....